# Error while starting docker daemon

Tags: docker

I get following error when starting Docker daemon from command line:

```
Error starting daemon: error while opening volume store metadata database: timeout
```

OS is Linux.

Any pointer how can I resolve this?
(Google search didn't yield anything)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your exact Linux distro, and docker version.

See for instance [issue 26022](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26022): it has the same error message on Fedora after a

```
 yum -y install docker-engine-1.13.1-1.el7.centos
```

Try and follow again the [full installation procedure for your exact distro](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/).

Answer (score 0):

After investigating a lot and **trying many commands**, this has worked for me:

`*Do not use '&&' to make the most compact command or otherwise it will not work.`

```
sudo rm /var/run/docker.pid
sudo systemctl stop docker.socket
sudo systemctl stop docker
systemctl start docker
systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```

If this error appears ( running `$ docker [command]` ):

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/mg/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

> 1. The first thing **you should do is to have Docker Desktop installed on your pc**, of which you can get here https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/

> 2. You should also **enable wsl2**, Just going through the documentation from the link above should be enough.

> 3. Also make sure **Settings > General > Use the WSL 2 based engine**... box is checked.

**REFERENCE** https://stackoverflow.com/a/72890783/21061651

Comment: What if I can't install Docker Desktop? I'm on my NAS and obviously can't install it