# docker：Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm remotely connecting to a school server (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) through Visual Studio Code (VScode, version 1.66) to perform some tasks, and today I follow docker.com (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) to install docker engine on Ubuntu.

when I do `sudo docker run hello-world` to verify that Docker Engine is installed correctly by running the `hello-world` image after all steps, it shows error like this:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

After that I check the `docker version`, it shows

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version: 20.10.14
 API version: 1.41
 Go version: go1.16.15
 Git commit: a224086
 Built: Thu Mar 24 01:48:02 2022
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Context: default
 Experimental: true
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Then look at `sudo docker info`, which shows

```
Client:
 Context: default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.8.1-docker)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.17.0)

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

After I unstall and reinstall docker follow this tutorial, it still shows such an error, I think I need to follow the server side of docker, but I don't know how to do it?

This is history:

```
root@yp:~# sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
...
root@yp:~# sudo apt-get update
...
root@yp:~# sudo apt-get install \
>     ca-certificates \
>     curl \
>     gnupg \
>     lsb-release
...
root@yp:~# curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
...
root@yp:~# echo \
>   "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
>   $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
...
root@yp:~# sudo apt-get update
...
root@yp:~# sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
...
root@yp:~# sudo docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should first start and enable docker in systemctl

```
systemctl start docker
systemctl enable docker
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it, but found:`root@yp:~#  systemctl start docker`
`System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`

Comment: @Yang did you install ubuntu on your pc or is it a VM or WSL?
Try this: sudo service docker start

Comment: No, I  didnot install ubuntu on my window10，Did I need to install Docker Desktop on my windows, like this (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/)?

Comment: I try `root@yp:~# sudo service docker start`, ` * Starting Docker: docker  `，but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, if using windows that doc is helpful.

Comment: Could you invite me to that discord too, or share the knowledge with which you finally resolved the issue - I'm experiencing the exact same sequence of problems with service docker start succeeding but still the "is the daemon running?" message.

Comment: I'm on Mac and get **zsh: command not found: systemctl**

Answer (score 14):

**Just solved a similar issue with this**

The first thing you should do is to have **Docker Desktop** installed on your pc, of which you can get here https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/

You should also enable wsl2,
Just going through the documentation from the link above should be enough.

Make sure you go into Settings>Resources>WSL Integration and enable Ubuntu-20.04 or any other distro you are using.

Also make sure Settings>General>Use the WSL 2 based engine... box is checked

Comment: Keep in mind the new licensing terms for Docker Desktop, which makes it a non-option for many

Answer (score 7):

I tried `usermod` and changed permissions, but still I was getting the same error on Linux. After digging up directories and files, I found docker is meant to connect symlink to `docker.sock` file but, it fails somehow.

```
ls -l /home/USERNAME/.docker/desktop
```

Check symlink for `docker.sock` to `/var/run/docker.sock` exist or not.

If the symlink doesn't exist, let's create one.

1. First backup original `docker.sock` file.

```
mv /home/USERNAME/.docker/desktop/docker.sock /home/USERNAME/.docker/desktop/docker.sock.bak
```

2. Create symlink

```
sudo ln -sv /var/run/docker.sock /home/USERNAME/.docker/desktop/docker.sock
```

You must see the output as:

`'/home/USERNAME/.docker/desktop/docker.sock' -> '/var/run/docker.sock'`

Run `docker run hello-world` again, it might be working now.

*P.S. I am seeing there are other files too in the same directory, they are not symlink. I will be attentive and if I face any error I would try creating symlink again for other files too. I will update my answer too.*

Comment: Folks, for anybody else facing this ".sock not found" error _after_ adding your user to the group, this helped me fix it in 2023.

Comment: This is the one that helped me. Adding the user to the group was not enough, adding/fixing the symlink did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

For Linux users arriving from search, also try:

- running the docker command without sudo (that's how rootless mode works)
- Add your user account to the docker group `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` [1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

Answer (score 3):

Mac users shall use `launchctl`—

```bash
sudo launchctl start docker
sudo launchctl enable docker
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the socket in

```
/var/run/
/var/run/docker.sock
```

I did not have, I ran

```
docker context ls
```

and had the output with DOCKER ENDPOINT

`unix:///var/run/docker.sock and unix:///Users/user/.docker/run/docker.sock`

So I created symbolic link. And everything worked fine

```
sudo ln -s /Users/user/.docker/run/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

**This fix worked for me:**

- Run `sudo update-alternatives --config iptables`
- Enter **1** to select **iptables-legacy**
- Run `sudo service docker` to start Docker

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem that you describe here :
"ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

I run docker desktop locally under linux with WSL2 enabled and the solution for me was :

- Go into the task manager
- Kill all active process of Docker desktop by selecting each and click "End the task" (several were trying to start)
- Start Docker desktop
- Then an update was automatically downloaded and installed (I don't know if it was it that was ruining the starting of docker)
- Then Docker start properly

### Good luck